# Terraform internal variable in resource definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this question that I am not sure how to formulate. So let use an example. I have the following resource definition for was subnets based in an input parameter variable:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "monitoring_subnetwork" {
  count = length(var.monitoring_subnets)

  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  cidr_block = var.monitoring_subnets[count.index]

  availability_zone= "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index % length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)]}"

  tags = {
    Name = "Monitoring private-1${replace(
      data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index % length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)], 
      data.aws_availability_zones.available.id, "")}"
  }
}
```

I want to simplify this code to make it more readable and maintainable.

I use a count.index to get an availability zone using round-robin, based on index % len_of_array, and the result of this mod is calculated twice (in other cases even three times).

I wonder if I could define an internal variable inside the resource, something like this:

```
zone_index = count.index % length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)
```

And reuse this index in the parts of the code where this operation is repeated.

Any thoughts? Also, any other recommendation to simplify this configuration would be appreciated :)

Comment: You don't have `zone_index` in your `aws_subnet" "monitoring_subnetwork` , so where would you use it?

Comment: on the name tag and the available zone definition to avoid repeating operations.

Comment: You can prepare a `map` with correct values in your `locals` with subnet as a key and zone as a value.
And use `for_each` instead of `count` after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you **can't do this**. There are **no custom functions** in terraform. But there is already a github issue for that, so maybe in future there will be added:

- [Extending terraform with custom functions](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27696)

So you have to keep repeating that computation.

Comment: @spotHound Yes. The same is lack for local variables in loops. Such variables would be useful.